# Rollbar overrides Laravel's exception handler

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, exception, rollbar

I'm using Rollbar in a Laravel 5.7 app, and the following situation has been confusing and frustrating me.

It seems that my `\app\Exceptions\Handler.php` file isn't getting used normally.

I finally noticed that https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/laravel#section-exception-logging says:

> "For Laravel 5.6, all errors which are normally handled by \App\Exceptions\Handler are going to be reported to Rollbar by default."

How can I disable this default functionality?

My `\app\Exceptions\Handler.php` will use `Log` to send data to Rollbar too, but it's important for me to run my whole exception handler since there is other functionality in there that needs to happen first.

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if this line is related to it: https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-php-laravel/blob/v4.0.3/src/RollbarServiceProvider.php#L40